# Defining binary variables in CPLEX

Tags: variables, optimization, binary, cplex

[Error in definition of binary variable in CPLEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKHoc.jpg) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKHoc.jpg)

the entries of x is either zero or any positive floating point number. For every nonzero value of x, corresponding entry of y is 1 otherwise its entry is zero. This code is written in CPLEX. But the error is getting due to binary nature of y. The code is in attached image.
Thankyou in advance for any help.[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2tP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2tP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For a binary the right keyword is boolean:

```
dvar boolean x;

subject to
{
  x==0;
}
```

works fine

Comment: I have to use strict inequality with x to calculate value of y. But problem is MILP, so CPLEX is not allowing to do this. How I can write constraint for y.

Comment: That s a diffèrent question right ?

Comment: No, this is the same question... Please check the model where I used "y" in objective function whose value depend on x. Basically "x" is used in supply, demand and conveyance constraint with another constraint "y" depending on "x".

Comment: Instead of >0 , why not using >=1 ?